# Opening childview back from scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a parent `ScrollView` with a child view. When the user presses the back button, I want the child view to handle the event. I have tried a couple of things but none of them seem to work. Pressing the back button kills the activity.

```
public class GameScrollView extends ScrollView{

     public GameScrollView(Context context) {
          super(context);
     }
     @Override
     public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev){
          return false;

     }
     @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
          return false;

     }
}
```

in the child view I have the following code

```
public class GameView extends View implements OnTouchListener, onKeyListener{

     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
          if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    //do stuff
          }
          invalidate();
          return true;        
     }
}
```

In the `ScrollView` I have also tried overriding the `dispatchKeyEvent`method to return false, but that did not work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason this was not working was because the child view did not have focus.

Setting the `requestFocus()` property in the constructor of the child view fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int i, KeyEvent event) {

      if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          return true;
        else {
          super.onKeyDown(i, event);
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Also, i think you'd have to intercept the keypress in your activity and not the View.

Comment: if I intercept the key press in the activity, how would I send it to the view to be handled? The view needs to do some drawing based on the key press.

Thanks.